# Módulo que se dice que falta mientras está en la lista de pip

Tags: python, librería, instalacion, environment, pytorch

Soy principiante con pytorch y me gustaria cargar y probar un model pyTorch para probar YOLO, un algoritmo de detección de objetos en tiempo real. Entonces hice un archivo muy simple para eso:

```
import torch
import os

PATH = "../RESULTS/YOLOV5_SMALL/TRAINED_NETWORK/yoloV5_small.pt"

model = torch.load(PATH)
model.eval()
```

Pero aqui esta lo que me contesta el terminal:

```
(yol_env) me@vm:/mnt/common/UC_Data_Folder/UC_avion/Models/ConfianceDelivery/yoloV5$ python ohlala.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/mnt/common/UC_Data_Folder/UC_avion/Models/ConfianceDelivery/yoloV5/ohlala.py", line 6, in <module>
    model = torch.load(PATH)
  File "/mnt/common/UC_Data_Folder/UC_avion/Models/ConfianceDelivery/yoloV5/yol_env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/serialization.py", line 607, in load
    return _load(opened_zipfile, map_location, pickle_module, **pickle_load_args)
  File "/mnt/common/UC_Data_Folder/UC_avion/Models/ConfianceDelivery/yoloV5/yol_env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/serialization.py", line 882, in _load
    result = unpickler.load()
  File "/mnt/common/UC_Data_Folder/UC_avion/Models/ConfianceDelivery/yoloV5/yol_env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/serialization.py", line 875, in find_class
    return super().find_class(mod_name, name)
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'yoloV5'
```

No sé porque me dice que falta `yoloV5` porque parece que lo hay:

```
(yol_env) antoine.coppin@sb01:/mnt/confiance/common/UC_Data_Folder/UC_Thales_Aerial_Photograph_Interpretation/Models/ConfianceDelivery/yoloV5$ pip list
Package                 Version
----------------------- ---------------------
absl-py                 1.0.0
albumentations          1.1.0
boto3                   1.21.18
botocore                1.24.18
cachetools              5.0.0
certifi                 2021.10.8
charset-normalizer      2.0.12
cycler                  0.11.0
fire                    0.4.0
fonttools               4.29.1
google-auth             2.6.0
google-auth-oauthlib    0.4.6
grpcio                  1.44.0
idna                    3.3
imageio                 2.16.1
imgaug                  0.4.0
importlib-metadata      4.11.2
jmespath                0.10.0
joblib                  1.1.0
kiwisolver              1.3.2
Markdown                3.3.6
matplotlib              3.5.1
networkx                2.6.3
numpy                   1.22.2
oauthlib                3.2.0
opencv-python           4.5.5.62
opencv-python-headless  4.5.5.62
packaging               21.3
pandas                  1.4.1
Pillow                  9.0.1
pip                     21.1.1
protobuf                3.19.4
pyasn1                  0.4.8
pyasn1-modules          0.2.8
pyparsing               3.0.7
python-dateutil         2.8.2
pytz                    2021.3
PyWavelets              1.2.0
PyYAML                  6.0
qudida                  0.0.4
requests                2.27.1
requests-oauthlib       1.3.1
rsa                     4.8
s3transfer              0.5.2
sahi                    0.9.0
scikit-image            0.19.2
scikit-learn            1.0.2
scipy                   1.8.0
seaborn                 0.11.2
setuptools              56.0.0
Shapely                 1.8.1.post1
six                     1.16.0
tensorboard             2.8.0
tensorboard-data-server 0.6.1
tensorboard-plugin-wit  1.8.1
termcolor               1.1.0
terminaltables          3.1.10
thop                    0.0.31.post2005241907
threadpoolctl           3.1.0
tifffile                2022.2.9
torch                   1.10.2
torchvision             0.11.3
tqdm                    4.63.0
typing-extensions       4.1.1
urllib3                 1.26.8
Werkzeug                2.0.3
wheel                   0.37.1
yolov5                  6.0.6
zipp                    3.7.0
```

Comment: `No module named 'yoloV5'` ¿No debería ser `import yolov5` (con **v** minúscula)?

Comment: Tienes razon @aeportugal esto significa que el model en python utilisando pyTorch framework fue mal escrito? En particular import yoloV5 fue escrito mientras que necesitamos yolov5?